# Como evitar teclado flutuante?

Tags: android

Estou testando meu aplicativo em um *tablet* da Samsung e o teclado número fica flutuante, o teclado fica em cima da minha aplicação, alguém sabe como desabilitar isso no código? Agradeço desde já!

**obs:** O teclado flutuante é exclusivo da Samsung, por isso não estou conseguindo resolver.

Comment: Descobri que este é um "problema" exclusivo dos dispositivos da Samsung.

Answer (score 5):

Se bem percebi apenas tens de adicionar

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Ou por xml:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Isto vai fazer com que o layout se adapte e dê espaço para o teclado abrir, não ficando por cima.

Comment: pelo que andei pesquisando o método que preciso usar é este mesmo, porém o parâmetro "SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE" não funcionou.

Comment: Como queres o teclado? pode ser que te ajude ;)

Comment: Tenho dois tipos de teclado, o de número e o de texto, o numérico está flutuante, eu consigo arrastar ele sobre minha tela (o que eu nem precisaria), mas ele sempre fica em cima da minha tela e o scroll não funciona, o teclado de texto está funcionando como preciso, ele abre mas não fica em cima da minha tela, com o scroll consigo percorrer toda a minha tela.

Comment: Tenta com getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
Não vai redimensionar o teu layout, mas tenta impedir que os componentes não sejam obstruídos.

Comment: agora o teclado de texto que estava ok ficou com o mesmo problema do numérico. desabilitou o scroll.

Comment: Tenta com estas flags http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html talvez te possa ajudar.

Comment: não deu certo. acho que por isso ser um problema específico do Samsung vai me dar dor de cabeça.